# Распространение своего приложения

Tags: распространение

Вот есть у меня идея для ПК приложения, есть мотивация его сделать и это получается (у меня уже есть такой проект). И предположим, я хочу чтобы кто то ещё пользовался моим приложением, и тоже пользовался его благами + предположим отправлял отзывы и баги мне на почту.

Но если загрузить даже екзешник на гит например, его никто не будет скачивать просто так.

Каким способом можно распространить свое приложение в сети даже не на коммерческой основе, бесплатно для меня и для пользователя? Может быть какие-нибудь площадки существуют?

Если что я говорю не о игре какой-нибудь или браузере, а о чем то нишевом, что нужно далеко не всем, как например какая-нибудь stamina или logisim.

Comment: Напиши о своем приложении в тематических сообществах, например, найди подходящее сообщество на реддите. Предложи там попробовать твое приложение. А на гитхабе можно выложить исходники, красиво оформить README и настроить релизы exe-файлов прямо там.

Comment: + к прошлому. Обязательно добавить поддержку английского языка - получите на порядок больше пользователей, отзывов и багов. Добавить описание, документацию в проект. Написать, как приложение собирается. Добавить roadmap развития проекта. Вот пример [удачного оформления](https://github.com/ArchiveBox/ArchiveBox). Гитхаб позволяет получать отзывы/баги через issues. Написать на [кикстартер](https://www.kickstarter.com/). Сайт проекта можно сделать на https://pages.github.com/ - положите туда готовые exe-сборки под все платформы для "хомячков".

Comment: У вас есть продукт. А для продукта справедливы все законы и правила маркетинга. Вас в данном случае интересуют бесплатные способы продвижения. Помимо способов, озвученных выше, можно: создать странички в соцсетях с описанием и ссылками на ваш репозиторий, создать веб-сайт продукта, приходить на платформы вопросов вроде я.кью и платформы отзывов. Находить темы, связанные с вашей, и в ответах предлагать попробовать ваш продукт. Если у вас есть блог, рассказать о продукте там.

Comment: @АринаАригри ну то что вы говорите это конечно хорошо, но моё приложение не настолько масштабное и долгоиграющее. То есть мне не нужно чтобы мое приложение стояло на каждом ПК, о нем знал каждый, я не хочу попасть в ролик топ самых успешных реклам. То что вы предлагаете, как по мне, это стать ну можно сказать маркетологом.  Все таки что мне нужно - это более пассивный вариант. То есть если я просто на открытый гит выложу, то максимум кто то случайно может ошибиться названием и попадет на мой проект, ну а например написать о приложении на том же реддите - это уже более подходит для меня

Comment: @Total Pusher вы предлагаете использовать reddit. А что на счет хабра. Мне хабр как то породнее, чем reddit или это совсем другое?

Comment: reddit рекомендовал @Vadik, а не я. Еще добавлю vc.ru. Если проект только на рынок СНГ - используйте хабр. Тут в СНГ в разы меньше как аудитория, так и программистов, которые могут поддержать проект. Если хотите пойти как Open Source - только зарубежные площадки. Все что я видел, что было сделано гражданами РФ - сделано на английском. Даже китайцы делают на английском. Попросту говоря, ваш проект в СНГ может никому не оказаться нужным.

Comment: Извините что так получилось, я думал вы это @Vadik. Ну а на русскоязычных пользователей вообще лучше не рассчитывать получается? Ну vs.ru это явно что то более подходящее чем просто гит